# L and R reference variable

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, c++14, rvalue-reference

I am trying to understand basic concepts of Rvalue and Lvalue reference variable and also that how they can be converted to each other (if possible) either as function parameter of as variables and to understand the memory operations involved in them - hence I cerated a class with required CTors and Dtor to understand temporary obejct creation / destruction during the operation:

```
class A
{
public:
   A() {std::cout << "CTor Called" << std::endl;}
   A(const A& a) {std::cout << "Copy CTor Called" << std::endl;}
   A(A&& a) {std::cout << "MOve CTor Called" << std::endl; }
   void operator =(const A& a){std::cout << "operator= Called" << std::endl;}
   ~A() {std::cout << "DTor Called" << std::endl;}
   void Show(){std::cout << "Show Called" << std::endl;}
};
```

First I am able to create R & L value reference variables:

```
    A a;
    A& a1 = a;
    const A& a2 = A(); // Lvalue using Rvalue
   //But I am unable to create R refererence variable using an L value variable
    A&& ra = a; // Does not work
    A&& ra = A(); // works
```

So is it that R value reference variables can only be created by R values unlike L values which can be ceated using an R value

Now I wrote up below templates:

```
template <class T> void fooNoRef(T tmp){tmp.Show();}
template <class T> void fooLRef(T& tmp){tmp.Show();}
template <class T> void fooRRef(T&& tmp){tmp.Show();}
```

But I am unable to call `fooRRef` function template using R value reference variable:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    A& a1 = a;
    const A& a2 = A();
    A&& ra = A();
    std::cout << "Calling fooNoRef Template Function" << std::endl;
    fooNoRef<A>(a);
    std::cout << "Calling fooLRef Template Function" << std::endl;
    fooLRef<A>(a);
    std::cout << "Calling fooRRef Template Function With Lvalue" << std::endl;
    fooRRef<A>(ra); // Does not works??
    fooRRef<A>(A());
}
```

So what are the concept of R and L reference variable and how to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I am unable to call `fooRRef` function template using R value reference variable:

You're confusing with *types* and [*value categories*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). As a named variable, `ra` is an lvalue and then can't be bound to rvalue-reference.

(emphasis mine)

> Each C++ expression (an operator with its operands, a literal, a
>   variable name, etc.) is characterized by **two independent properties: a
>   *type* and a *value category***.
>
> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - the name of a variable, a function`, a template parameter object (since C++20)`, or a data member, regardless of type, such as `std::cin`
>     or `std::endl`. **Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the
>     expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression**;

On the other hand, it could be bound to lvalue-reference, e.g.

```
fooLRef<A>(ra); // works
```

You can also convert it to rvalue explicitly by [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move), e.g.

```
fooRRef<A>(std::move(ra)); // works
```

> Names of rvalue reference variables are lvalues and have to be
>   converted to xvalues to be bound to the function overloads that accept
>   rvalue reference parameters, which is why move constructors and move
>   assignment operators typically use `std::move`:

Comment: What does std::move does and then what hapens to variable ra?

Comment: @Programmer Convert the argument to rvalue.

Comment: So to an Lvalue reference variable both R and L reference variable can be assigned but an R value can only be assigned to R reference variable - right?

Comment: @songyuanyao xvalue, to be exact.

Comment: @Programmer Precisely, lvalues could be bound to lvalue-reference but not rvalue-reference, rvalues could be bound to rvalue-reference and lvalue-reference to const but not lvalue-reference to non-const.

Comment: @Programmer lvalue reference to const can bind to both lvalues and rvalues, but we cannot modify the objects through them.

Comment: @JohnDing Yes, xvalues are rvalues. I don't use the term to avoid making OP more confusing.